# Eclipse - How To Remove Packages

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started taking this Distributed Systems class, and my teacher says the following on our class website:

> Please do NOT use packages! If your configuration of Eclipse uses them
>   by default, please remove them before writing code!

What the heck is she talking about? I thought eclipse NEEDS to create packages for your project source files to stay organized. How do I remove them?

Comment: If you don't give the package a name, the classes will be placed in the default package. This is discouraged by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages are not mandatory. If you create a new project in Eclipse, you can directly add your classes to src folder. These files will be under **/workspace/project_name/src/** folder. If you add a package, your class files will be placed under **/workspace/project_name/src/package_name** folder. Your instructor will need to know package names to be able to compile your files and she is probably using a script or something to automatically compile them and that script assumes your files are placed under src folder.

Comment: Ok I just did that and it put my .java file under the "default package", like what @mvd said, but now I don't have to include that line `package "something`, which is what I think she wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first line of your code if exist that says:

```
package <package-name>;
```

And if you are creating a new class, then don't give any package name.

Comment: Thanks, the warning eclipse gave me about default packages scared me, which is why I put the name because I thought it was required. I thought there was a way to turn off that requirement. brifbraff gave a correct answer first, but +1 for you, thanks!